# MongoDB run javaScript file from console and output

Tags: javascript, mongodb, console

I am trying to create some mongoDB script (files upload to collections, find, create new collections etc). Though get confused. When I run in console:

```
> use importCSV    
> db.people.find().pretty()
```

I get documents from collection on my screen, though when I run load command

```
> load('e:/work/parse/script.js')
```

i get output

```
true
```

Here javaScript file list

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('importCSV');
db.people.find().pretty();
```

I do it for debug purpose, so I create javaScript line by line to get what I want, and I need to see step by step some commands output. If I put to javaScript file command like this

```
print('Print from javaScript file');
```

it prints to console without any problems.

Why I get "true" when run from file instead of console output, and how to get list of documents printed when run from javaScript file?

Thanks

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: You right :) Edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an expected behaviour. You need to iterate through the cursor and print each document explicitly using a [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop because you are not using the interactive shell.

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('importCSV');
db.people.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    printjson(doc);
}
```